# guitar tab creator

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь создать что-то похожее на редактор гитарной табулатуры. Проблема в том, что при попытке ввода с клавиатуры в textarea, она перестает реагировать на нажатие кнопок вообще. Код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var e =" E | ",
        a =" A | ",
        d =" D | ",
        g =" G | ",
        z = "\n",
        tabby = $("#tab"),
        leng = $("#leng"),
        main = "",
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
    tabby.text(main + z + now);


    $("#bb").click(function(){
        e += "--";
        a += "-2";
        d += "--";
        g += "--";
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z ;
        tabby.text(main + z + now);
        leng.html(now.length);

        if (now.length >= 184) {
            main += z + now;
            e =" E | ";
            a =" A | ";
            d =" D | ";
            g =" G | ";
            now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
            tabby.text(main + z + now);
        }
    });

    $("#abb").click(function(){
        e += "---";
        a += "---";
        d += "---";
        g += "-10";
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z ;
        tabby.text(main + z + now);
        leng.html(now.length);

        if (now.length >= 184) {
            main += z + now;
            e =" E | ";
            a =" A | ";
            d =" D | ";
            g =" G | ";
            now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
            tabby.text(main + z + now);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#tab {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 15px;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 7px;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
#buttons {
  width: 245px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#leng {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="tab"></textarea>
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" id="bb">add "fu" tab</button>
  <button type="button" id="abb">add "ck" tab</button>
  <div id="leng"></div>
</div>
```

**Как это исправить?**

З.Ы. Прошу прощения за код. Мои знания js/jquery жутко ограничены.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы текст с клавиатуры в textarea вообще нельзя было вводить или чтобы после введения всё работало, как раньше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать `.text()` для полей ввода не рекомендуется, измените на `.val()`, всё будет работать.
А вот для DIVа `.text()` самое то и, наверное, даже правильнее `.html()`, хотя в конкретно этом случае без разницы.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var e =" E | ",
        a =" A | ",
        d =" D | ",
        g =" G | ",
        z = "\n",
        tabby = $("#tab"),
        leng = $("#leng"),
        main = "",
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
    tabby.val(main + z + now);


    $("#bb").click(function(){
        e += "--";
        a += "-2";
        d += "--";
        g += "--";
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z ;
        tabby.val(main + z + now);
        leng.text(now.length);

        if (now.length >= 184) {
            main += z + now;
            e =" E | ";
            a =" A | ";
            d =" D | ";
            g =" G | ";
            now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
            tabby.val(main + z + now);
        }
    });

    $("#abb").click(function(){
        e += "---";
        a += "---";
        d += "---";
        g += "-10";
        now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z ;
        tabby.val(main + z + now);
        leng.text(now.length);

        if (now.length >= 184) {
            main += z + now;
            e =" E | ";
            a =" A | ";
            d =" D | ";
            g =" G | ";
            now = e + z + a + z + d + z + g + z;
            tabby.val(main + z + now);
        }
    });
});
```

Чтобы вообще ничего нельзя было вводить в textarea, добавьте в тег "readonly":`<textarea id="tab" readonly></textarea>`